# Highlight Every Other Excel Row Based on Changing Value

Tags: vba, excel, loops

So let's say I have a spreadsheet in which the values in the first column go like so:

> 1
>
> 1
>
> 1
>
> 2
>
> 2
>
> 4
>
> 4
>
> 6

I want to highlight every other grouping of values. Meaning the first 3 rows, all containing 1, would be highlighted one color. Then the 2s would have no fill. Then the rows containing 4 in the first column would be highlighted the same color as the first block.

Essentially, I want to alternate fill/no fill every time the value in the first column changes. These values are not necessarily numeric, so if a new column is needed with transposed numeric values, please let me know.

Thanks for checking out my question. If clarification is needed, do not hesitate to ask.

Comment: It would be great if you showed us what you've got, we can help fix it.

Comment: That's a great idea but unfortunately I haven't written anything yet as I am working on other aspects of this macro and still trying to figure out how to best approach this piece of it.

Comment: Generally speaking, you'll get a lot more help by trying something (use the macro recorder to get you started, if need be) and posting a specific issue, than by asking for someone to do it for you.

Comment: Check my answer to almost exactly the same problem (conditional formatting without helper columns): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28673964

Comment: ^ Awesome, this looks like it will be perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did the following:

1) Make sure you have a blank row in `row 1`. Your data begins on `row 2`, `Column A`.

2) Put value: `0` in cell `B1`.

3) Put this formula in cell `B2`, and copy it down:

```
=OFFSET(B2,-1,0,1,1)+IF(A2=OFFSET(A2,-1,0,1,1),0,1)
```

4) Create conditional formatting using this logic:

```
=mod($b1,2)=1
```

So that formula in (3) is just finding the "groups" by looking for the changes in value.
Then you do the conditional formatting on `Mod 2` for every 2nd row.

Comment: This looks promising, I'll let you know how it goes when I've had a chance to experiment. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional formatting. This should be on the home tab on the ribbon. It is best to know which values will be in there as you can format them based upon this fact.

Comment: Viable, however I think it would take a new rule for each new value, and it would rely on them being in a certain order so you can ensure the colors alternate. I think VBA would be a simpler choice.